# C# ADO.Net Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between DBNull.Value and int

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm coding a small app that inserts data into an access database, so far so good but i can't seem to insert NULLs into the nullable fields.

I tried:

```
myAccessCommand.Parameters
    .Add("@IDACCOMPAGNATEUR", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 
        (ActivityRegistration.id_invitee == 0 
         ? DBNull.Value 
         : InviteeWebToSGM[ActivityRegistration.id_invitee]);
```

and

```
myAccessCommand.Parameters
    .Add("@IDACCOMPAGNATEUR", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 
        (ActivityRegistration.id_invitee == 0 
         ? (int?)null 
         : InviteeWebToSGM[ActivityRegistration.id_invitee]);
```

But both don't work with different issues. My initial thought was to use DBNull.Value but it cannot be converted to anything near INT should it be INT or INT?. My second try works but returns an error message stating that there is no default value for my field but it does allow NULL. So my guess is that null in ADO.Net is not the same thing as DBNull.value...

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO `DBNull.Value` is definitely the way to go.

try

```
myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDACCOMPAGNATEUR", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 
(ActivityRegistration.id_invitee == 0 ? DBNull.Value : (object) InviteeWebToSGM[ActivityRegistration.id_invitee]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null` (or `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null.Value`, I'm not entirely sure and can't try right now):

```
myAccessCommand.Parameters
    .Add("@IDACCOMPAGNATEUR", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 
        (ActivityRegistration.id_invitee == 0 
         ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null.Value
         : InviteeWebToSGM[ActivityRegistration.id_invitee]);
```

Comment: Results in SQLNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values;

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the most annoying thing about ADO.NET, but it is what it is. Yes, you need to use DBNull.Value, and to fix the compile error, cast to object.

```
myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDACCOMPAGNATEUR", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 
    (ActivityRegistration.id_invitee == 0)
     ? (object)DBNull.Value 
     : (object)InviteeWebToSGM[ActivityRegistration.id_invitee];
```

Comment: Would work, but the first cast on DBNull.value is useless, thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDACCOMPAGNATEUR", OleDbType.Integer?).Value = 
(ActivityRegistration.id_invitee == 0 ? DBNull.Value : InviteeWebToSGM[ActivityRegistration.id_invitee]);
```

Comment: the datatype of the parameter might need to be nullable indicated by a question mark after the datatype

Comment: Doesn't compile with OleDbType.Integer?

Comment: depends on the version of your C#, in C# 3.0 there are so-called nullable types, not sure though